# Are the spells learned from the "Touched" feats considered class spells when cast using spell slots?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, spellcasting

The Fey Touched and Shadow Touched feats published in *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* each grant the use of two spells.  Among other things, they say:

1. You learn the [spells].
2. You can cast each of these spells without expending a spell slot [once per long rest].
3. You can also cast these spells using spell slots you have of the appropriate level.

The spellcasting ability for these spells is specific to the feat, so it may or may not be the same as the ability of a class that grants spell slots.

---

Casting classes all have their own quirks regulating their spellcasting features, but these shouldn’t be relevant to how the Touched feats’ spells are cast in #2 because that casting isn’t using a spellcasting feature.  This is clear because even non-casting classes can cast the spells in this way, so only the *generic* spellcasting rules apply there.

(This is related to why racial feat spells can’t be cast with a focus, as discussed at [If a spellcaster's racial trait grants a spell that requires material components, can they use their class' focus to cast that spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/170685/if-a-spellcasters-racial-trait-grants-a-spell-that-requires-material-components))

However, things get more complicated when the feats’ spells are cast as described in #3, because the spell slots referenced there *do* come from a class spellcasting feature.  In that case, does the caster simply use the spell slot as “fuel” and otherwise cast the spell exactly as it had been cast for #2?  Or is this inherently different, with the caster actually using their class spellcasting feature and therefore having to follow all of its specific rules?

Furthermore, is the answer different depending on whether the specific Touched feat spell being cast is on the caster’s class’ spell list or not?

---

Potentially Related:

[Does Magic Initiate allow the chosen spell to effectively be “always prepared” if the spell is on their spell list?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/167728/does-magic-initiate-allow-the-chosen-spell-to-effectively-be-always-prepared-i)

[What makes a spell being cast considered to be a {class} spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106182/what-makes-a-spell-being-cast-considered-to-be-a-class-spell)

[Are spells learned from feats considered to be associated with your class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110954/are-spells-learned-from-feats-considered-to-be-associated-with-your-class)

Comment: Extremely related (do any of these answer your question): "[Are spells learned from feats considered to be associated with your class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110954)" and "[Can I use spell slots to cast the spell granted from the Fey Teleportation feat additional times?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110944)" and "[If you have the ability to cast a spell without a spell slot, can you cast that spell using a spell slot?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102875)"

Comment: The last two links' answers don't go beyond whether you can also cast the spells being discussed with spell slots.  The Touched feats explicitly say that you can, so I don't think those are relevant.  The first link doesn't seem to answer my question either, but it may help inform the thoughts of anyone who chooses to answer, so I'll add a link to it above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116552/discussion-between-gto-and-thomas-markov).

Comment: This seems to be a question that is a subset of/ *should* be covered by a complete answer to the linked [What makes a spell being cast considered to be a {class} spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106182/what-makes-a-spell-being-cast-considered-to-be-a-class-spell); I think the only reason it isn't is because the rules around this are sadly vague for all cases. I'm tempted to bounty that to get new attention since these feats present a new point of confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Only select feats associate their spells with a class

Let's look at the [Sorcerer's Spellcasting feature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#Spellcasting-369):

> [...] The Sorcerer table shows how many spell slots you have to cast your sorcerer spells of 1st level and higher. [...]

From this we can conclude that the spell slots from the Sorcerer class can be used to cast a spell *only if* that spell is a Sorcerer spell (whatever that means).

---

The [Sage Advice Compendium](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice/sage-advice-compendium) ([pdf link](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf)) states the following about the Magic Initiate feat (emphasis mine):

> Q. If you have spell slots, can you use them to cast the 1st level spell you learn with the Magic Initiate feat?
>
> A. Yes, but ***only if* the class you pick for the feat is one of your classes.** For example, if you pick sorcerer and you are a sorcerer, the Spellcasting feature for that class tells you that you can use your spell slots to cast the sorcerer spells you know, so you can use your spell slots to cast the 1st-level sorcerer spell you learn from Magic Initiate. [...]
>
> In short, **you must follow your character’s normal spellcasting rules**, which determine whether you can expend spell slots on the 1st-level spell you learn from
> Magic Initiate.

From this we can conclude two things:

1. A spell granted by a feat that explicitly links the spell to a given class is associated with that class (a Sorcerer taking Magic Initiate under *Sorcerer* and choosing to learn *magic missile* can use their spell slots to cast *magic missile*; therefore, *magic missile* *must* be considered a Sorcerer spell).
2. A spell that is granted by a feat and appears on our class spell list is not *necessarily* associated with our class (a Sorcerer taking Magic Initiate under *Wizard* and choosing to learn *magic missile* **cannot** use their spell slots to cast the spell; therefore, *magic missile* must *not* be considered a Sorcerer spell).

Thus, most spells gained from feats are *not* associated with any class whatsoever. The most notable exception is Magic Initiate, which associates the spell with whichever class you pick. Other examples would be Ritual Caster and Spell Sniper as well as the Wood Elf Magic feat's cantrip in particular which is required to be a Druid cantrip.

---

The feat in question does *not* associate the spells learned from it with a particular class; thus they *do not* count as class spells for whoever is casting them and they are not subject to various requirements or usable with various abilities that say "When you cast a {class} spell..."

Instead, what this feat says is:

> [...] You can also cast these spells using spell slots you have of the appropriate level. The spells' spellcasting ability is the ability increased by this feat.

This means that you are explicitly able to use your spell slots on these spells ([a rather rare thing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/169117)), however they are *not* associated with your class. This is especially clear given that their spellcasting ability need not be the same as the one your class actually uses, though even if they were the same, this would still be the case.

---

#### A big list of related questions

That all said, ultimately, whether a given spell is associated with your class and considered a class spell is up to the GM. We have several questions on this (and related topics) with numerous differing answers:

- [What makes a spell being cast considered to be a {class} spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/106182)
- [Are spells learned from feats considered to be associated with your class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110954)
- [What is an "artificer spell" for Infuse Magic?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110650)
- [Does Confusion cast via the Dreadful Word invocation count as a warlock spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/141536)
- [Can the artificer's spell-storing item store their specialist spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/170460)
- [Can I use my best spellcasting ability for Eldritch Adept?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/188619)
- [If I am a Celestial Warlock and I take the Magic Initiate - Cleric (Cure Wounds), does that now count as a Warlock spell for me?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/157765) [duplicate]
- [What counts as a sorcerer spell for the purposes of the Wild Magic sorcerer's Wild Magic Surge feature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177727) [duplicate]

---

- [Can a sorcerer spell cast from a magic item trigger a Wild Magic Surge?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/131710)
- [Could a Wild Magic Surge be triggered by a Wild Magic Sorcerer using a Magic Initiate spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/107253)
- [Wild Magic Surge activation without using spell slots](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/94891)
- [For Ring of Spell Storing, when does Wild Magic Surge trigger?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/93954)
- [Can the 1st-level spell learned through the Aberrant Dragonmark feat trigger a Wild Magic Surge?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/175126)
- [Does Wild Magic Surge trigger off of spells on the Sorcerer spell list, if I learned them from another class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/143269)
- [Can you cast a spell learned from the Magic Initiate feat using spell slots?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/68451)
- [Can you trigger Wild Magic Surges with rituals?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/111884)

---

- [If you have the ability to cast a spell without a spell slot, can you cast that spell using a spell slot?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102875)
- [Can I use spell slots to cast the spell granted from the Fey Teleportation feat additional times?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110944)
- [Does Magic Initiate allow the chosen spell to effectively be "always prepared" if the spell is on their spell list?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/167728)
- [If I take the Magic Initiate feat and choose a different class, but pick a spell that's also on my class's list, can I cast it using spell slots?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/151256)
- [Can an Arcane Trickster or Eldritch Knight with the Magic Initiate feat (picking the wizard list) use spell slots to cast the chosen 1st-level spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/176665)

---

- [Does casting a spell from an item allow you to apply class abilities that are used when casting a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50054)
- [Can a spell being cast via a magic item be considered to be more than one class' spell at the same time?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/141543)
- [Can you retrain the Magic Initiate spell using the Spellcasting feature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/49731)
- [Can spells from the Magic Initiate feat be swapped out for different ones?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/134996)
- [As a Sorcerer, can you trade out the spells granted by the Drow High Magic feat?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138947)
- [Does the "Cantrip Formulas" optional Wizard feature allow a racial cantrip to be swapped for another?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/188127)

Comment: You make a good argument for the "fuel" interpretation -- and I'm happy with that from a thematic perspective, too, because it seems more consistent with what these feats' mechanics are intending to convey.